Rendering AgGrid React table blocking main thread
After updating AgGrid from 25.x.x to 32.3.3, rendering of table blocks main thread. To isolate the issue, I created both Plunker and CodeSandbox examples which work just fine. However, if I copy exact same code to my project, rendering is lagging. It takes more then 150ms to render a simple table. I thought that complex build process may affect the code in unwanted way, so I created a brand new local project with Vite react-ts starter. Table rendering behaves the same with clean build. Tried it out in several different browsers (latest versions) with all extensions turned off.
Code example: https://plnkr.co/edit/92owMwLJbkRnlpKP?open=index.tsx
Plunker

